# Trying to access an onpremise business central server via NTLM Auth, from Android(400 Error)

Tags: android, ntlm, dynamics-business-central, ntlm-authentication

The issue is, im trying to access a Webservice on the server, and the server has NTLM Auth. Everything works fine in Postman, since i just specified a username and password and there are no issues getting the JSON i want. I have tried adding all the same headers to my android code, and i have checked multiple times that both the URL and the username/password are correct, i am not sure why im still getting a 400 Bad Request Error, im pretty lost, any help is appreciated.

```
package com.example.recumasapp.Conexión;

import okhttp3.*;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GetJson {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "the url";

    private static final String USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String DOMAIN = "";

    private static final String AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = "NTLM";

    public interface ApiService {
        @GET
        Call<String> getData(@retrofit2.http.Url String url);
    }

    public String access(String lista) throws IOException {
        String authHeaderValue = createNtlmHeader();

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new NtlmAuthInterceptor(authHeaderValue));
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        String url = BASE_URL + "Company('Recumas')" + lista;
        Call<String> call = apiService.getData(url);

        try {
            retrofit2.Response<String> response = call.execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return response.body();
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response.code() + ": " + response.message());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Error executing API request: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String createNtlmHeader() {
        String domainUser = (DOMAIN != null && !DOMAIN.isEmpty()) ? DOMAIN + "\\" + USERNAME : USERNAME;
        String authString = domainUser + ":" + PASSWORD;
        byte[] authBytes = authString.getBytes();
        String encodedAuth = AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX + " " + android.util.Base64.encodeToString(authBytes, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return encodedAuth.trim();
    }

    private static class NtlmAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
        private final String authHeaderValue;

        public NtlmAuthInterceptor(String authHeaderValue) {
            this.authHeaderValue = authHeaderValue;
        }

        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request authenticatedRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", authHeaderValue)
                    .header("Accept", "*/*")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using different libraries, including jcifs, okhttp and retrofit, but i still get the same 400 Bad Request Error, i used all the same headers as postman showed me, but same issue once again. I have also checked that the url and credentials are right, but i cannot think of any other solution nor what i might be doing wrong.